# What is the proper grammatical usage of *hamentaschen*?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, purim, yiddish

Possibilities:

singular / plural

hamentasch / hamentaschim

([as seen here](http://www.english-hebrew-dictionary.com/purim-5.htm))

hamentaschen / hamentaschen

I believe the second option prevails colloquially. Is there a correct/incorrect usage of this Yiddish word? Does it matter?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Because it's a word that is pretty much only used in connection with Purim (and I guess by bakeries the rest of the year, if they try to sell them year-round), this feels on-topic to me.

Answer (score 4):

I went looking for instances of "hamentash" (המן־טאַש) in Sholom Aleichem stories because I wanted to see it used in a sentence as singular and plural. In the story "Two Shalachmones or A Purim Scandal" the word is used 12 times, but every single usage is singular.  It is consistently spelled המן־טאַש or "hamentash".  You can find the first instance on [page 58 (page 62 of the file)](http://www.archive.org/stream/nybc202588#page/n62/mode/2up) in the paragraph at the bottom of the page.  The next eight instances are all on [page 60 (page 64 of the file)](http://www.archive.org/stream/nybc202588#page/n64/mode/2up) in a humorous jabbering conversation between the two women characters.

Regarding your question about the Yiddish spelling, a Google search returns results for spelling the plural with a "ן", but not with a "ם" at the end. It looks like  the evidence so far confirms Wikipedia's assertation that:

> A hamantash (or hamentasch, see: Other names; Yiddish המן־טאַש, pl. hamantashen or hamentaschen)

Wikipedia does not give a spelling for the Yiddish plural, but Google searches reveal two common spellings "המן טאשן" and "המן-טאשן" (with a space or with a hyphen).

One story that I know has the plural hamantashen is "Two Dead Men" about Chlavne the drunk and his wife Gittel, but I cannot seem to find that in the original Yiddish.

Comment: According to the YIVO Standard Yiddish spelling system, there should always be a hyphen (called a makef) between המן and טאַש.  Of course, many people (including notably most of the Chassidish world) does not hold by YIVO spelling.

Also, [these](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43653&st=%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F&pgnum=172) [dictionaries](http://cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi?word=homentash), among [others](http://www.verterbukh.org/), back up the makef, along with your spelling and your plural (המן־טאַשן).

Answer (score 2):

For most words in Yiddish, the "ן" or "en" at the end of a noun makes it plural. So "המן-טאשן" means many hamentashen, and "המן-טאש" is the singular. (EX: I ate a hamentash. We ate 3 hamentashen each.)